# Oracle database have any feature to add Sensitive Data Indicator to a Column?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Does Oracle supports storing columns Sensitive Indicator similar to following SQL Server ?

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (SNAME VARCHAR(1000))

ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
dbo.STUDENT.SNAME
WITH ( LABEL='Highly Confidential', INFORMATION_TYPE='Financial', RANK=CRITICAL )
```

Then we can fetch this Information with the following query.

```
SELECT *FROM sys.sensitivity_classifications
```

Is Oracle Database have any feature similar to this?

SQLServer Documentation : [SQLServer_Documention_For_Sensitive_Data_Indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-sensitivity-classification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: They have [transparent sensitive data protection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-transparent-sensitive-data-protection.html#GUID-2C55E6BF-8FD9-4537-B649-88AB788002A5) which sounds broadly similar, though maybe more advanced than you're looking for if you just want to tag or label columns. But that was added in 12c; are you really on 10g or 11g?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. So my answer is a bit outdated. As this request is for Oracle 10 or 11, it may show the only option, though, if you don't want to upgrade. These versions are quite old, however, so upgrading sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As far as I know, Oracle doesn't have this feature.</strike> Oracle introduced transparent sensitive data protection in Oracle 12c. Please see Alex Poole's comment and the link he posted on that.

If it's only about adding this information to a column in order to find it in the database, you can always add comments on columns to the data dictionary that you can use for this purpose:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN mytable.mycolumn IS 'SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION="Highly Confidential", INFORMATION_TYPE="Financial", RANK="CRITICAL"';
```

You can find these columns as follows for example:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_col_comments WHERE comments LIKE '%SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION%';
```